# Runge-Kutta Butcher tables

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration

I like to have the Butcher's table for Explicit (or implicit as well) Runge-Kutta method of a fixed order.

I do not understand reading http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2013/09/10/numerical-methods-runge-kutta-algorithms/ and http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html if it is possible to produce such tables let's say for Runge-Kutta 6th order method or implicit Lobatto 12th order (for example).

I know there are many analytical ways to compute this tables (actually these is the reason why there are many different Runge-Kutta schemes I guess), but I like to have the coefficients used by the Runge-Kutta integrators in Mathematica.

Could some one help me?

Thanks !

Comment: Something like ``NDSolve`EmbeddedExplicitRungeKuttaCoefficients[6, Infinity]``?  See also ``?NDSolve`*Coefficients*``.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you. It was what I needed but, when I try, using the ``?NDSolve`*Coefficients*`` to change the method, let's say, I want the Implicit Lobatto Method IIIA I receive every time the same output as the input: I type ``NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients[6, Infinity]`` and the output is ``NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients[6, Infinity]`` and anything else.

Comment: I put my comment in an answer, with references.  I did not have the problem you report with ``NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients``.  I'm not sure what the issue is.  The code executes fine on a fresh kernel, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tutorial ["ExplicitRungeKutta" Method for NDSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html#1456351317) shows how to get the built-in coefficients for the the default 2(1) embedded pair:

```
NDSolve`EmbeddedExplicitRungeKuttaCoefficients[2, Infinity]
(*
  {{{1}, {1/2, 1/2}}, {1/2, 1/2, 0}, {1, 1}, {-(1/2), 2/3, -(1/6)}}
*)
```

The general syntax for a given method, order, and precision appears to be

```
methodCoefficients[order, precision]
```

The tutorial [The Design of the NDSolve Framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDesign.html#74982980) shows that the default coefficients for a method may be found through the method's `"Coefficients"` options.

```
Options[NDSolve`ExplicitRungeKutta]
(*
  {"Coefficients" -> "EmbeddedExplicitRungeKuttaCoefficients", 
   "DifferenceOrder" -> Automatic, 
   "EmbeddedDifferenceOrder" -> Automatic, 
   "StepSizeControlParameters" -> Automatic, 
   "StepSizeRatioBounds" -> {1/8, 4}, 
   "StepSizeSafetyFactors" -> Automatic, "StiffnessTest" -> Automatic}
*)
```

I could not find definitive lists of settings for `"Coefficients"` for each method, but things to try may be found in the following list:

```
? NDSolve`*Coefficients
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One may also define one's own coefficients as shown in the ["ExplicitRungeKutta" documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveExplicitRungeKutta.html#1391088597).

Examples:

```
NDSolve`EmbeddedExplicitRungeKuttaCoefficients[6, MachinePrecision]
(*
{{{0.18}, {0.0895062, 0.0771605}, {0.0625, 0., 0.1875},
  {0.316516, 0., -1.04495, 1.25843}, {0.272326, 0., -0.825134, 1.04809, 0.104716},
  {-0.166994, 0., 0.631709, 0.17461, -1.06654, 1.22721},
  {0.364238, 0., -0.204049, -0.348837, 3.26193, -2.7551, 0.681818},
  {0.0763889, 0., 0., 0.369408, 0., 0.248016, 0.236742, 0.0694444}},
 {0.0763889, 0., 0., 0.369408, 0., 0.248016, 0.236742, 0.0694444, 0.},
 {0.18, 0.166667, 0.25, 0.53, 0.6, 0.8, 1., 1.},
 {0.0176887, 0., 0., -0.111317, 0.853412, -0.956633, 0.236742, 0.128687, -0.16858}}
*)

NDSolve`ImplicitRungeKuttaLobattoIIIACoefficients[6, Infinity]
(*
{{{0, 0, 0, 0}, {1/120 (11 + Sqrt[5]), 1/120 (25 - Sqrt[5]), 
   1/120 (25 - 13 Sqrt[5]), 
   1/120 (-1 + Sqrt[5])}, {1/120 (11 - Sqrt[5]), 
   1/120 (25 + 13 Sqrt[5]), 1/120 (25 + Sqrt[5]), 
   1/120 (-1 - Sqrt[5])}, {1/12, 5/12, 5/12, 1/12}},
 {1/12, 5/12, 5/12, 1/12},
 {0, 1/10 (5 - Sqrt[5]), 1/10 (5 + Sqrt[5]), 1}}
*)
```

The OP reported in a comment that this last example returned unevaluated.  I did not observe that (as can be seen).  Earlier, I had tried the order 12 with infinite precision, which ran for a while before I aborted it; however, with the `MachinePrecision`, the computation finished quickly.

*Update (3/2019):*

I wrote at some point this little utility for formatting *Mathematica's* Butcher tables.  For embedded rules, the last row is not the integration rule but the error rule, which is the difference of the two rules.  I just came across this old answer and thought it was a good place to share the utility:

```
ClearAll[rkButcherTable];
rkButcherTable[a_, b_, c_, e_: Nothing] := Grid[
   PadLeft[#, {Automatic, 1 + Length@First@#}, 
      List /@ Join[{0}, c, Take[{"b", "err"}, Length[{b, e}]]]] &@
    PadRight[
     Join[{{""}}, a, {b, e}],
     Automatic,
     ""],
   Dividers -> {{2 -> Black}, {Length@a + 2 -> Black}}
   ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]